# Failed to establish a network connection [Errno 111] within Docker container on server

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, centos, linode

I have a working python script on my local computer, and it works on the server without Docker, it consumes twitter data from the twitter api (I don't use tweepy).

When I try to run it from a docker container on Linode, my CentOS server, I get

```
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fab73c152d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fab73c152d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

ALTHOUGH, I can successfully do `requests.post` (i.e. my bearer token is correct), which I do to update my twitter rules. So why can't I do `requests.get`?

Do I need to open a port on the server? and the docker container?

Here's my stream function:

```py
def get_stream(headers, sleep=10):
    include_fields = ",".join(["author_id", "created_at", "public_metrics"])
    url_with_query_params = (
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields={}".format(
            include_fields
        )
    )
    response = requests.get(
        url_with_query_params,
        headers=headers,
        stream=True,
    )

    if response.status_code != 200:
        if sleep >= 500:
            sys.exit("Just couldn't connect.", response.status_code, response.text)
        time.sleep(sleep)
        get_stream(headers, sleep + 2 * sleep)
    latest_tweet = datetime.now()
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            try:
                result = json_response["data"].copy()
            
                result["polarity_scores"] = sia.polarity_scores(result["text"])
                result["matching_rules"] = json_response["matching_rules"]
                es.index(index='tweets',id=result["id"],body=result)
                print(result['id'])
          
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY secrets.json secrets.json
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY filtered-stream.py filtered-stream.py
RUN python3 -m nltk.downloader vader_lexicon
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python","filtered-stream.py"]
```

Comment: Please include the Dockerfile in your question. I suspect that the server that you're using binds to localhost and, when run under Docker, is inaccessible to the host.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, I've included the Dockerfile now! It does seem to bind to localhost seeing as I don't specify it to bind to anything else

Comment: I misunderstood your question and thought you were unable to access the process in the container. If you're able to make the `POST` against the API's method then you're correct in assuming a `GET` (against the same API) should work. Even though you include a Python function `get_stream`, it's unclear how you invoke this function. Please include the code that shows the `POST` and the `GET` so that we may attempt to discern the difference.

Comment: BTW it's potentially problematic to `COPY secrets.json secrets.json` into a container image. If you inadvertently `push` the image, it's possible someone else could obtain your credentials. Since `secrets.json` is likely only needed at `docker run ...` (time) rather than `build`, you may wish to consider either mounting the secret or providing it through the environment.